# Microsoft Windows Update schedule

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, windows-update, automatic-updates

I'm currently have Windows server 2012r2 and it's getting updates from WSUS automatically (download,install,restart).
my question is how could i tell when the restart is going to happen?
our policy is that this is happening in the weekends but i don't know which weekend because every server has it's own update progress, one could be fully updated and the other just missed a few updates.
i'm not always in front of my servers and i would like to know a few days or what possible before the restart is going to happen.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot set a specific time for a restart. If you choose
AUoptions 4 - "Auto download and schedule the install" it will install patches at the set time and day of the week (there is no possibility to choose day of the month either...)
Then it depends on how long the installation will take and server will just reboot if the update requires it. Also the configuring phase after reboot can take long time and usually much longer then the phase before reboot (especially on w2k16 servers).

There are however some options like "No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations" so it will show a fullscreen message notifying user that restart is needed and they can can keep delaying it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/deploy/4-configure-group-policy-settings-for-automatic-updates